# System::Collections::Generic::List of Custom class objects c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to create a list of my custom class "Bandset" to a System::Collections::Generic::List in a Singleton class. But whenever I add any new item to the list, all the previous elements also become the same. Please find the code below.

BandsetData.h

```
namespace ConfigToolApplicationData {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;

public ref class Bandset
{
private:
    String ^bandsetTabName;
    DataTable ^bandsetTable;

public:     
    Bandset()
    {
        bandsetTable = gcnew DataTable();
    }       
    static property String^ Name { String^ get() { return bandsetTabName; } void set(String ^ value) { bandsetTabName = value; }};
    static property DataTable^ Table { DataTable^ get()
    {
        if (!bandsetTable)
            bandsetTable = gcnew DataTable();
        return bandsetTable;
    }
    void set(DataTable ^ value)
    {
        bandsetTable = value;
    }
    };
};
};
```

SharedData.h

```
namespace ConfigToolApplicationData {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;

public ref class SharedData
{
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::List<String^> ^tabList;
    static System::Collections::Generic::List<Bandset^> ^bandsetTabList;
    SharedData() {}
    SharedData(const SharedData%) { throw gcnew System::InvalidOperationException("singleton cannot be copy-constructed"); }
    static SharedData m_instance;
    static int awardSymbolTableCount;
    static int bandsetTableCount;
    static int controlTableCount;
    static int paylineTableCount;
    static int awardSymbolTableIndex;
    static int bandsetTableIndex;
    static int controlTableIndex;
    static int paylineTableIndex;

public:
    static property SharedData^ Instance { SharedData^ get() { return %m_instance; } }
    static property int AwardSymbolTableCount { int get() { return awardSymbolTableCount; } void set(int value) { awardSymbolTableCount = value; }};
    static property int BandsetTableCount { int get() { return bandsetTableCount; } void set(int value) { bandsetTableCount = value; }};
    static property int ControlTableCount { int get() { return controlTableCount; } void set(int value) { controlTableCount = value; }};
    static property int PaylineTableCount { int get() { return paylineTableCount; } void set(int value) { paylineTableCount = value; }};
    static property int AwardSymbolTableIndex { int get() { return awardSymbolTableIndex; } void set(int value) { awardSymbolTableIndex = value; }};
    static property int BandsetTableIndex { int get() { return bandsetTableIndex; } void set(int value) { bandsetTableIndex = value; }};
    static property int ControlTableIndex { int get() { return controlTableIndex; } void set(int value) { controlTableIndex = value; }};
    static property int PaylineTableIndex { int get() { return paylineTableIndex; } void set(int value) { paylineTableIndex = value; }};
    static property System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>^ tabNameList
    { System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>^ get()
    {
        if (!m_instance.tabList)
        {
            m_instance.tabList = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>();
            m_instance.tabList->Clear();
        }
        return m_instance.tabList;
    }
    }
    static property System::Collections::Generic::List<Bandset^>^ bandsetTabNameList
    { System::Collections::Generic::List<Bandset^>^ get()
    {
        if (!m_instance.bandsetTabList)
        {
            m_instance.bandsetTabList = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<Bandset^>();
            m_instance.bandsetTabList->Clear();
        }
        return m_instance.bandsetTabList;
    }
    }

    void SharedData::RemoveBandsetTab(String ^name)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < m_instance.bandsetTabList->Count; index++)
        {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Table->TableName);
            if (m_instance.bandsetTabList[index]->Name->Equals(name))
                m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->RemoveAt(index);
        }
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Count);
    }
    void SharedData::AddBandsetTab(String ^name)
    {
        Bandset^ bandset = gcnew Bandset();

        bandset->Name = name;
        bandset->Table->TableName = name;
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Before");
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Count);
        for (int index = 0; index < m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Count; index++)
        {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(index);
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Name);
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Table->TableName);
        }
        m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Add(bandset);
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("After");
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Count);
        for (int index = 0; index < m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Count; index++)
        {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(index);
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Name);
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Table->TableName);
        }
    }
};
```

};

I call them from a function in another class as follows:

```
SharedData ^sharedData = SharedData::Instance;
wchar_t wcs[80];
wcscpy_s(wcs, AWARD_SYMBOL_TABLE_STRING);
            wcscat_s(wcs, std::to_wstring(++sharedData->AwardSymbolTableIndex).c_str());
sharedData->AddBandsetTab(gcnew String(wcs));
```

If I call this once then the list contents are:

- bandSetTable1

If I call it the second time then the contents become:

- bandSetTable2
- bandSetTable2

I don't know what is the issue. I am very new to C++/CLI.

Could anyone please point out the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. Because of that, C++/CLI has all of the complexities of C++, all of the complexities of C#, and some complexities of its own. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

```
public ref class Bandset
{
private:
    static String ^bandsetTabName;
    static DataTable ^bandsetTable;

public:
    static property String^ Name { String^ get() { return bandsetTabName; } void set(String ^ value) { bandsetTabName = value; }};
}
```

You have both of these properties defined statically. This means that there's only one name and one data table, both of which are shared by all band sets.

```
void SharedData::AddBandsetTab(String ^name)
{
    Bandset^ bandset;// = gcnew Bandset();

    bandset->Name = name;
```

So here, `bandset` is `nullptr`, because you didn't initialize it. The only reason that `bandset->Name` didn't throw a `NullReferenceException` is because `Name` is a static property, so the value of the instance (currently `nullptr`) isn't used at all.

```
    m_instance.bandsetTabNameList->Add(bandset);
```

This just inserted `nullptr` into the list.

```
    Debug::WriteLine(m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]->Name);
```

Again, because `Name` is a static property, the fact that `m_instance.bandsetTabNameList[index]` is `nullptr` doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I pasted the old code. I actually tried with making them non static and that time I was getting the above mentioned output. Also the  code was this. `Bandset^ bandset = gcnew Bandset();`

Comment: Edit your question with the actual code you're using, please.

Comment: Edited, please have a look now. :)

Comment: @DavidYaw Jeff intern cspeed. any ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529050/runtimebinding-exception-working-with-vectors-of-string